# How to link an image in input text box using css

Tags: html, css

I can position a background image using the background property in an input field but I want an action to trigger when it is clicked.

Can I trigger an action on a background image click?

I just want to place a small 'X' image over the right hand side of input which clears the input.

Comment: Don't do that. Background images are backgrounds. Use an `<img>`, preferably inside a `<button type="button">` (if you want to reset the whole form, use `type="reset"` then you don't even need JS). Wrap the input and the button in a container (maybe a `<span>`). Then apply CSS. Get rid of the border on the input, put a border on the span. It ends up looking the same as if you were doing background tricky, but is much more accessible, much more logical, and much easier to achieve.

Comment: I have used img previously but wanted to see if using a background was achievable.  When using a background, you can position it realtive to the input - when using img, you have to position it relative to the containing element... It is definitely achievable but I wanted to explore background usage

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can absolutely position a link over the `<input>` and then apply a `text-indent` to the `<input>` to make room for the image. For example:

```
<div id="outer">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="alert('click')"><img src="http://placekitten.com/16/16"></a>
    <input type="text">
</div>
```

And:

```
#outer {
    position: relative;
}
#outer a {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
#outer input {
    text-indent: 16px;
}
```

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/TgaFf/

The outer `<div id="outer">` is just there to give me something to apply `position: relative` to; absolutely positioned elements are positioned with respect to the nearest ancestor whose `position` is anything other than `static`. The `text-indent` on the `<input>` starts the input cursor 16px from the left side of the `<input>` and thus leaves space for the image. In the real world you would, of course, adjust the `top`, `left`, margins, paddings, ... to make everything line up properly and look pretty.

Comment: Thanks, I thought this would be the only way.  I was trying to achieve it as a background image but I guess that is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

sorry i misunderstood your question, add a class to the input, and you can do it with a jquery click function or a javascript onClick

Comment: Does that mean I can intercept a click only in the coordinates of the image or will it be responsive to the entire input area?

Comment: you want the whole input to be clickable or just a small image inside the input? sorry im a bit slow just woke up

Comment: Yeah, I was looking for just the small image to be clickable, not the whole input.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, if you can pass a class to it with Jquery/ js. Otherwise there are some CSS3 options like transitions - to animate, see www.css3please.com Depends what you're wanting to do?

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">

  function callmee()
  {
    alert("call");
  }

   </script>
</head>

<body>
    <input type="button" style="background-image:url(shahrukh2.jpg);" onclick="callmee()"></div>
</body>
```

i think, u want this..

regardz

Comment: While it isn't explicit, the implication in the question is fairly clear: The goal is to have a clickable thing inside a text input that will clear the text input.

Comment: Sorry, i didn't read your full requirements.. it's my mistake